# "Dog bone" integral when computing $\int_{-1}^{1} \mathop{\mathrm{d}x} \frac{(1-x)^{-2/3}(1+x)^{-1/3}}{4+x^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

> **Problem.** Evaluate the integral, using appropriately chosen contour as shown in the figure:
>
> $$ \int_{-1}^{1} \mathop{\mathrm{d}x} \frac{(1-x)^{-2/3}(1+x)^{-1/3}}{4+x^2} $$
>
> [image: 1]
>
> Remember that when complexifying keep the argument between $-\pi$ and $\pi$

I'm learning complex integration and I am facing difficulties in solving this problem after trying several times.

I know that the function is analytic on this contour so the closed integral on the green contour would be zero. In my calculation the residue of f(x) at x= 1 and x= -1 is coming out to be zero. I used a "dog bone" contur to integrate it.

How to calculate it ?

Someone please help me out.

Comment: For $|z| > 2$ and with any choice of branches, we should have $$ |f(z)| \leq \frac{1}{(|z| - 1)(|z|^2 - 4)}. $$ So the integral along the outermost circle $C_R$ satisfies $\left|\int_{C_R} f(z) \, \mathrm{d}z\right|\leq CR^{-2}$ for all sufficiently large $R$ for some constant $C>$, and so, it vanishes as $R\to\infty$.

Comment: I'm quite sure I saw this exact question here several hours ago and commented on it then. Did you delete and repost it?

Comment: @Troposphere It seems to be the case, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4317101/dog-bone-contour-integral

Comment: @Troposphere Yep. I've reposted this problem .

Comment: You need to prove that the relevant branch of $f$ is analytic on $|z|>1$ so that $\int_{C_R} f(z)dz$ doesn't depend on $R$, then use what Sangchui Lee said. Letting $R\to 1^+$ you (almost) get the $\int_{-1}^1 f(z)dz$ integral.